# Share currently active printer with VirtualBox

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, printer

In a laptop there are 3 different printers installed, one for each location (home and offices) that the laptop is used. If I share the printer using the USB interface, Virtualbox can use it, but this makes the printer offline on host PC. If I share the printer using network interface, I'll have to have 3 different network shares.

Is it possible to have some kind of personal printer server that would be the single point of access? I mean, this printer server has all 3 printers, but creates a single network share.

Host PC is Windows 10 and VM is running Windows XP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to solve this issue is to put the Printers on your Network (that is, NOT shared).

If need be, get USB Print Servers, or more hopefully, printers have built in network capability.

Once done, any Host or VM can use the printer (I do this here with hosts and virtual machines).

Printing this way on a VM does not disconnect any host.

You need to install the Printer driver on each machine, but if you shared that is already likely the case.

Summary: Network Printing, not Print Sharing.